# Relationship between oculometry/pupillometry and disorders of consciousness

Tags: vision, consciousness, eye-movement, unconscious

I recently got to wondering whether certain eye movements or pupillary responses were correlated with disorders of consciousness (coma, VS, MCS, or even locked-in syndrome).  I know that the pupillary response to a direct light-source is part of the usual coma evaluation scale, but my question deals more with resting-state oculomotor activity or stimulus-evoked responses.

An example of such research might be (for example) a paper in which changes in pupil response co-varies with conscious-state changes in an MCS patient.

Does anybody know of any such research?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have listed several articles below for your reference:

(Search terms: "**oculometry pupillometry disorders of consciousness**" in Google Scholar, nothing special):

[Grandchamp et al, 2014, DOI: 10.3389/fpsyg.2014.00031](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3920102/) - A primary research article related to consciousness (mind wandering) where the authors investigated various pupillometric responses, among other measures. Good journal.

(Search terms: "**pupillometry consciousness**" in Google scholar):

[Laeng et al., 2012, DOI 10.1177/1745691611427305](http://pps.sagepub.com/content/7/1/18.short) - Nice looking review on pupillometry and consciousness that should be a good source of additional references;

[Smallwood et al., 2011, DOI: 10.1371/journal.pone.0018298](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0018298) - A primary research article on attention and perception in Plos One. It is open source, but not my favorite journal